# A simulation from reality vs simulation from reality.

Tags: articles

"While previous simulations were often accused of predictability and lack of immersion, now it was almost impossible to distinguish simulation from reality."

"While previous simulations were often accused of predictability and lack of immersion, now it was almost impossible to distinguish a simulation from reality."

The second is correct grammar-wise, but is the first also correct under certain circumstances?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The second is correct grammar-wise, but is the first also correct under certain circumstances?

Yes; in fact, there are two completely separate reasons that it's correct:

- The noun *simulation* can be either a count noun (as in ["one simulation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22one+simulation%22&tbm=bks), ["two simulations"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two+simulations%22&tbm=bks)) or a mass noun (as in ["[…] used simulation to […]"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22used+simulation+to%22&tbm=bks)). So if we mean that simulation *in general* is very realistic now (as opposed to a *specific* simulation), then we can use *simulation* in its mass-noun sense and drop the *a*. (Even in that case, however, it would also be fine to use its count-noun sense and include the *a* — one use of indefinite singular count nouns is to represent a generic instance, as in "A cheetah can run faster than a lion" — or to use the plural *simulations*, à la "Cheetahs run faster than lions".)
- In formal English, the "distinguish X from Y" frame does not require *a*'s even when X and Y are count nouns; hence ["distinguish question from answer"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22distinguish+question+from+answer%22&tbm=bks) and ["distinguish body from soul"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22distinguish+body+from+soul%22&tbm=bks). I would consider this an example of what [*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) calls "matched nouns" frames that do not require determiners (chapter 5, section 8.5, page 409); it gives the examples of *from father to son*, *from beginning to end*, *between husband and wife*, and *mother and child*.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are fine.

The article is used when there is a specific instance of something that you are talking about; without the article, you are generally talking about the idea of something (without instantiation).

In your example sentence, you might use an article if you were at a virtual reality exposition and comparing VR gear from different specific vendors—or different VR worlds provided by the same vendor.

Similarly, in fiction it's possible to talk about different specific realities with the use of an article. (Even in the real world, people will sometimes rhetorically refer to *your* reality or *my* reality—although almost rarely *a* reality.)